# Redirecting to a page in .NET passing in an id

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to redirect users to a 'Delete' page in a .NET Core application, after they press a delete button next to the item that they intend to delete.

I'm using: RedirectToPage("./Delete", new { videoId = Video.Id }), passing in an id and redirecting users to a view, but at the moment I'm getting an error saying "This page isn't working at the moment - localhost redirected you too many times".

Is there another way of coding this so that the page is built and the user is sent straight through? I have also tried using Page() but I am aware that this cannot take any arguments.

Code:

```
        public IActionResult OnGet(int? videoId)
        {
            Video = videoId.HasValue ? _videoData.GetVideo(videoId.Value)
                : new Video
                {
                    ReleaseDate = DateTime.Now.Date
                };

            return Video == null ? RedirectToPage("./VideoError", new
            {
                message = "The video does not exist"
            }) : (IActionResult)
            RedirectToPage("./Delete", new { videoId = Video.Id });
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Page it should redirect to:

[image]

Thanks, Robert

Comment: Where is the delete button located? Another question, why are you creating a new video if the video id is null?

Comment: When you submit a form, your handler should simply be: `OnPost` instead, then you can delete the video inside that.